# How do I have text fade in to a UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Right now I have an IBAction for a button which generates a random number with each number assigned to display text in a UILabel. Rather than just appear, I would like the text to fade in or any other interesting animation would be cool too. Does anyone know a simple way to make this happen?

Right now I just use

```
labelMain.text = @"my text";
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following code will give you fading effect on your label.

```
 - (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
  {
    labelMain.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
    animations:^{ labelMain.alpha = 1;}
    completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the first one up and it worked like a charm! Very simple and easy to adjust the duration and add a delay too!

Answer (score 31):

I know this is a bit stale (11 months old), but I think it's worth mentioning an alternative to the other approaches posted, which I feel is a better solution.

Make use of the `UIView transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion` class-level method, like this:

```
NSTimeInterval duration = 0.5f;
[UIView transitionWithView:labelMain
                  duration:duration
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                  labelMain.text = @"new value";
                } completion:nil];
```

This will cross-fade from the previous value of `labelMain.text` to "new value".

This approach works on other view values as well, such as changing the image of a UIImageView, for instance.

See [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW112) on the topic.

Comment: Just a tip in case anyone wants to animate lots of labels in the same superview, just use your superview in the `transitionWithView` argument.

Comment: This is the best way to do it. don't know why this is not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
label.text = @"old text";
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        label.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        label.text = @"next text";
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            label.alpha = 1.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"finished transition");
        }];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[labelMain setAlpha:0];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
[labelMain setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Changing the duration is pretty simple - just adjust the value `0.8` in the code.

Comment: Blocks are more powerful. You should consider dropping beginAnimations for animateWithDuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
// fade out the current value
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                      delay:0
                    options:0
                 animations:^{
                   labelMain.alpha = 0.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   // set the new value and fade in
                   labelMain.text = newValue;
                   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                                         delay:0
                                       options:0
                                    animations:^{
                                      labelMain.alpha = 1.0f;
                                    }
                                    completion:nil];

                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will look like cross fade animation

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
        animations:^{
    labelMain.alpha = 0;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
        animations:^{ labelMain.alpha = 1;}
        completion:nil];

    } completion:nil];
```