# Swift UIView.animate between many different strings

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm looking to recreate the animation on the Welcome screen present on the iPhone once booted up from a fresh device - the greetings you see in various different languages seen here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZDbGyvAK7o

My issue is that I have about 20+ strings I want to fade in/out between but I'm not convinced that creating 20+ different UILabels is the most efficient method to approach this. There must be another way to do this rather than hard coding it.

Here's what I have so far with keyframes

```
//textC UIlabel declaration and initialising its' properties.   
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: total, delay: 0, options: [.calculationModeLinear, .repeat], animations: {

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1/total, animations: {
                let attributedStrD = NSMutableAttributedString(string: countryArr[0], attributes: resultAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])
                print(attributedStrD.string)
                textC.attributedText = attributedStrD

            })

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1/total, relativeDuration: 1/total, animations: {
                let attributedStrD = NSMutableAttributedString(string: countryArr[0], attributes: resultAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])
                textC.alpha = 0
                textC.attributedText = attributedStrD

            })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2/total, relativeDuration: 1/total, animations: {
                textC.alpha = 1
                let attributedStrD = NSMutableAttributedString(string: countryArr[1], attributes: resultAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])
                textC.attributedText = attributedStrD
                print("2")
            })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 3/total, relativeDuration: 1/total, animations: {
                textC.alpha = 0

                let attributedStrD = NSMutableAttributedString(string: countryArr[1], attributes: resultAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])
                textC.attributedText = attributedStrD
            })

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 4/total, relativeDuration: 1/total, animations: {
                textC.alpha = 1

                let attributedStrD = NSMutableAttributedString(string: countryArr[2], attributes: resultAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])
                textC.attributedText = attributedStrD
            })

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 5/total, relativeDuration: 1/total, animations: {
                textC.alpha = 0

                let attributedStrD = NSMutableAttributedString(string: countryArr[2], attributes: resultAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])
        textC.attributedText = attributedStrD
            })
        }) { (_) in
             print("done animation")
        }
```

This also doesn't quite work, as the text doesn't update, instead the last string in the array is seen when built and run on the simulator.

Update:
Though I wanted to avoid timers it seems that's the only method that works for me. So I made a UIView extension that fades the label using a CATransitionView, you can find an example of it on stackoverflow. Then I created a Timer that would run the fade animation and cycle through the strings using one label

Comment: You only need one label - See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358417/how-do-i-have-text-fade-in-to-a-uilabel) (Not the accepted answer, the highest voted one) - It is Objective C, but you should be able to figure out how to use `transitionWithView` in Swift pretty easily

Comment: Thanks. Saw the answer you were referring to. But I don't see how using the superivew as the argument would be the approach to use lots of different strings/labels

Comment: No, I have no idea what that comment is about.  You only need one `UILabel`; you just animate the new piece of text into it

Comment: Just one label would suffice. All you need to do is alter the animate the alpha of that label and when alpha is 1 (meaning it is not visible) update the text of the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UIView.transition` to cross fade the text in a single `UILabel`, using a `Timer` to initiate the next animation:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.textLabel.text = self.strings[stringIndex]

    let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        self.stringIndex = (self.stringIndex + 1) % self.strings.count

        UIView.transition(with: self.textLabel, duration: 0.8, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.textLabel.text = ""
        }, completion: { (Void) in
            UIView.transition(with: self.textLabel, duration: 0.8, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                self.textLabel.text = self.strings[self.stringIndex]
            }, completion: nil)
        })

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using this:

```
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.label.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { (finished) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                self.label.alpha = 1.0

                let text = self.quotes.remove(at: 0)
                self.label.text = text
                self.quotes.insert(text, at: self.quotes.count-1)
            })
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@bigubosu This should work:

```
var strings = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    animate()
}

func animate() {
    guard strings.count > 0 else { return }

    let alpha:CGFloat = textLabel.alpha == 0 ? 1 : 0

    if alpha == 1 {
        textLabel.text = strings.remove(at: 0)
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.textLabel.alpha = alpha
    }, completion: { [weak self]  (finished) in
        self?.animate()
    })
}
```